# YOLO 'C' compilation failure with DEBUG=1

Tags: opencv, gdb

I am trying to compile YOLO with GPU=1, OPENCV=1, DEBUG=1. The same combination with DEBUG=0 got compiled successfully but when I make with DEBUG=1 its resulting in compilation failure.

```
>>make
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/gemm.c -o obj/gemm.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/utils.c -o obj/utils.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/cuda.c -o obj/cuda.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/convolutional_layer.c -o obj/convolutional_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/list.c -o obj/list.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/image.c -o obj/image.o
./src/image.c: In function ‘load_image_cv’:
./src/image.c:488:16: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cvLoadImage’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     if( (src = cvLoadImage(filename, flag)) == 0 )
                ^
./src/image.c:488:14: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     if( (src = cvLoadImage(filename, flag)) == 0 )
              ^
./src/image.c: In function ‘save_image_jpg’:
./src/image.c:530:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cvSaveImage’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     cvSaveImage(buff, disp,0);
     ^
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/activations.c -o obj/activations.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/im2col.c -o obj/im2col.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/col2im.c -o obj/col2im.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/blas.c -o obj/blas.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/crop_layer.c -o obj/crop_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/dropout_layer.c -o obj/dropout_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/maxpool_layer.c -o obj/maxpool_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/softmax_layer.c -o obj/softmax_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/data.c -o obj/data.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/matrix.c -o obj/matrix.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/network.c -o obj/network.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/connected_layer.c -o obj/connected_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/cost_layer.c -o obj/cost_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/parser.c -o obj/parser.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/option_list.c -o obj/option_list.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/darknet.c -o obj/darknet.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/detection_layer.c -o obj/detection_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/captcha.c -o obj/captcha.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/route_layer.c -o obj/route_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/writing.c -o obj/writing.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/box.c -o obj/box.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/nightmare.c -o obj/nightmare.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/normalization_layer.c -o obj/normalization_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/avgpool_layer.c -o obj/avgpool_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/coco.c -o obj/coco.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/dice.c -o obj/dice.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/yolo.c -o obj/yolo.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/detector.c -o obj/detector.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/layer.c -o obj/layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/compare.c -o obj/compare.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/classifier.c -o obj/classifier.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/local_layer.c -o obj/local_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/swag.c -o obj/swag.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/shortcut_layer.c -o obj/shortcut_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/activation_layer.c -o obj/activation_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/rnn_layer.c -o obj/rnn_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/gru_layer.c -o obj/gru_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/rnn.c -o obj/rnn.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/rnn_vid.c -o obj/rnn_vid.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/crnn_layer.c -o obj/crnn_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/demo.c -o obj/demo.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/tag.c -o obj/tag.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/cifar.c -o obj/cifar.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/go.c -o obj/go.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/batchnorm_layer.c -o obj/batchnorm_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/art.c -o obj/art.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/region_layer.c -o obj/region_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/reorg_layer.c -o obj/reorg_layer.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/super.c -o obj/super.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/voxel.c -o obj/voxel.o
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU -c ./src/tree.c -o obj/tree.o
nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU" -c ./src/convolutional_kernels.cu -o obj/convolutional_kernels.o
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU" -c ./src/activation_kernels.cu -o obj/activation_kernels.o
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU" -c ./src/im2col_kernels.cu -o obj/im2col_kernels.o
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU" -c ./src/col2im_kernels.cu -o obj/col2im_kernels.o
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU" -c ./src/blas_kernels.cu -o obj/blas_kernels.o
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU" -c ./src/crop_layer_kernels.cu -o obj/crop_layer_kernels.o
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU" -c ./src/dropout_layer_kernels.cu -o obj/dropout_layer_kernels.o
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU" -c ./src/maxpool_layer_kernels.cu -o obj/maxpool_layer_kernels.o
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU" -c ./src/network_kernels.cu -o obj/network_kernels.o
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU" -c ./src/avgpool_layer_kernels.cu -o obj/avgpool_layer_kernels.o
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
gcc  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wfatal-errors  -O0 -g -DOPENCV -DGPU obj/gemm.o obj/utils.o obj/cuda.o obj/convolutional_layer.o obj/list.o obj/image.o obj/activations.o obj/im2col.o obj/col2im.o obj/blas.o obj/crop_layer.o obj/dropout_layer.o obj/maxpool_layer.o obj/softmax_layer.o obj/data.o obj/matrix.o obj/network.o obj/connected_layer.o obj/cost_layer.o obj/parser.o obj/option_list.o obj/darknet.o obj/detection_layer.o obj/captcha.o obj/route_layer.o obj/writing.o obj/box.o obj/nightmare.o obj/normalization_layer.o obj/avgpool_layer.o obj/coco.o obj/dice.o obj/yolo.o obj/detector.o obj/layer.o obj/compare.o obj/classifier.o obj/local_layer.o obj/swag.o obj/shortcut_layer.o obj/activation_layer.o obj/rnn_layer.o obj/gru_layer.o obj/rnn.o obj/rnn_vid.o obj/crnn_layer.o obj/demo.o obj/tag.o obj/cifar.o obj/go.o obj/batchnorm_layer.o obj/art.o obj/region_layer.o obj/reorg_layer.o obj/super.o obj/voxel.o obj/tree.o obj/convolutional_kernels.o obj/activation_kernels.o obj/im2col_kernels.o obj/col2im_kernels.o obj/blas_kernels.o obj/crop_layer_kernels.o obj/dropout_layer_kernels.o obj/maxpool_layer_kernels.o obj/network_kernels.o obj/avgpool_layer_kernels.o -o darknet -lm -pthread  `pkg-config --libs opencv`  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lstdc++ 
obj/image.o: In function `cvPointFrom32f':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h:929: undefined reference to `cvRound'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h:930: undefined reference to `cvRound'
obj/image.o: In function `cvReadInt':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h:2350: undefined reference to `cvRound'
obj/image.o: In function `cvEllipseBox':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h:1041: undefined reference to `cvRound'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h:1042: undefined reference to `cvRound'
obj/darknet.o:/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h:929: more undefined references to `cvRound' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:63: recipe for target 'darknet' failed
make: *** [darknet] Error 1
```

Somehow I get a strong feel that its the problem with opencv or its compatibility with gdb.

Any Ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6076) may be of interest

Comment: I have checked that @RobertCrovella but I guess solution mentioned over there is for c++ whereas I am using YOLO in 'C'. Including such header file will cause me language compilation problems as I am compiling YOLO with gcc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I reported the problem to opencv regarding this bug and received a strange response!! here is the thread related to this:
[opencv3 bug related to cvRound](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8438)

They mentioned that OpenCV support for C doesn't work all the time properly when compiled with gcc.

So, I modified the opencv code temporarily in order for the debugger to work:

Changes I have done are:
replaced **cvRound** with **ceil** by including math.h in the files `opencv2/core/types_c.h` `opencv2/core/core_c.h` and `opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h` in `/usr/local/include` with root permissions

Then the YOLO code got compiled successfully with DEBUG=1

Alternately - if you don't want to change openCV code - you can do similar workaround in one of the yolo files. For example: in beginning of detector.c add:

`#include "math.h"
int cvRound(double value) {return(ceil(value));}`

Answer (score 5):

Regarding this problem here is the [answer](https://github.com/leggedrobotics/darknet_ros/issues/1#issuecomment-298329957) that helped to resolve the issue.

In original yolo/darknet you can see that in order to debug  [Joseph Redmon](https://pjreddie.com/) pass **do not optimize flag to gcc** [here](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/Makefile#L36):

```
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1) 
OPTS=-O0 -g
endif
```

But, to resolve that issue you could just use optimizations which [do not conflict with debugging](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), replace in [Makefile](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/Makefile) with:

```
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1) 
OPTS=-Og -g
endif
```

I think issue totally related with optimization options. And originally the author doesn't meet that problem because he uses [Intel Core i7-5820K](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/hardware-guide/) which has some specific attributes and conflict doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

> Somehow I get a strong feel that its the problem with opencv

Correct: it's not uncommon for developers to only compile with `DEBUG=0` and never try `DEBUG=1` (or vice versa). Whichever setting is the default gets tested, and the non-default setting is only fixed when users report problems (which you should do).

> or its compatibility with gdb.

This has *nothing* to do with GDB.

Comment: but what could be the problem? Any idea?

Comment: @praneeth The problem is a bug in opencv. Try a later version, and if reproduces report it.

Comment: currently I am using opencv 3.2, the latest version of opencv.. So i guess I need to report about this. How can I do that? Any help? Sorry I have never done that before.

Comment: Also, I found this is the issue: "cvRound is not defined for C-API due to it was moved from include/opencv2/core/types_c.h to include/opencv2/core/fast_math.hpp". So for now, I am trying to fix it temporarily in order to compile my code. I tried adding the path "opencv2/core/fast_math.hpp" in opencv2/core/types_c.h under "#ifdef __cplusplus" but that didn't help. Any other ways of solving this problem temporarily for now?

Comment: I followed this link in making an attempt to solve my issue temporarily: [https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/6586]